# recall saved position object

Tags: modeling, transforms, saving

if the topic had already been discussed, I'm sorry, I don't know what kind of keywords to use for the search.

I come from the Autodesk "Vred" world and I speak of "Vset" a module where different positions of the same object are stored and can be recalled with certain shortcuts.
example: I have an ikea chest of drawers. by clicking on a vset set with the name "first drawer" the column was presented with the first drawer open and the others closed, then clicking on the "second drawer" Vset set the second drawer open and the others closed and so on, then finally with vset " tuttochiuso ”the chest of drawers was set up with the drawers all closed. it should be noted that it was not an animation but a way to speed up the view of the object without having to act individually on the objects with the drag to close and open.
so I ask you, hoping to have been clear, if there is a way to act in the same way on blender. I just ask you for the names of the modifiers, objects or command name and then I study it for myself. so far I have tried with animations but it did not convince me, with armor but I am too early in the program and I am still finishing a general course on blender. I ask you for a little patience.

thanks to many and i hope to read your answers
sorry my english, i use google translate

dd.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should look into the new *Pose Library*. It's still a work in progress so it may lack some basic functions but it works:

[image]

You first need to activate the addon *Animation: Pose Library*. Then create an armature and parent each object to one of the bones with the *parent to bone* method: Select the object, shift select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, select the bone you want for this object and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Bone*.

Now in *Pose* mode, open the *N* panel, click on the *Animation* tab, move the bone(s) you want the way you want and click on the *Create Pose Asset* button, it will add the pose as a new thumbnail, you'll just have to click on this thumbnail to call back the pose.

To manage the assets (like to give it another name or put it into a catalog), open an *Asset Browser* window. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pd_ftb0z5g) you have a tutorial by The CG Essentials that explains more (but you'll find several other ones).

Other than that, you have the *Action* constraint, but it seems a bit more complicated.